# Darksiders 2 - DE on PS4 pro: freezes, crashes, etc

Tags: ps4, darksiders-2

As a PS Plus member, I downloaded Darksiders 2 DE earlier this month to play it on my PS4 Pro.

Except the video introduction, the game is freezing / crashing almost every minute I'm playing.

I try a lot of things, including:

- disabling high quality shadows
- disabling damage indicator
- disabling Boost Mode (on the PS4 settings)
- disabling subtitles

That's too bad, I played for 5 minutes and it seems to be a fun game.

Any tips or help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated PS4 OS to 5.03 and it did solve my issues.

EDIT : Well, it didn't solve all my freezing issues with this game. I disabled high quality shadows to make it more stable.

Comment: Well this is actually helpful and is the kind of Q&A question style that should be upvoted